# Heroku automatic db backup via cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is it possible to backup Heroku database using cron jobs?

I tried putting the following line into **cron.rake**:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire
```

However it didn't work. The line works when I run it from Terminal.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [heroku_s3_backup](https://github.com/edavis10/heroku_s3_backup) gem, which packages up the code necessary to do this in a neat way.

Comment: But how do I use this with the storage space that PGBackups provides for free?

Comment: PGBackups has it's own tools as part of the Heroku command: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Answer (score 1):

The gem [heroku_backup_task](https://github.com/joemsak/heroku_backup_task) integrates directly with the free PG Backups add-on for Heroku.