# What command(s) does `heroku pgbackups:capture` run on the server to perform backups?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

Since Heroku migrated to their new database tiers, I've found myself without the automated backup plan provided by the `pgbackups` addon, as I'm only on a basic plan.

I'd happily run a daily `pgbackups` backup using the `cron` addon, if I knew what commands were actually executed on the remote side when I run `heroku pgbackups:capture --expire` on my end via the toolbelt.

My applications are all Python apps using the Cedar stack, so I'm not sure that the gem-based auto-backup options mentioned in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019352/heroku-automatic-db-backup-via-cron-job) are available to me (some of those also mention backing up to S3, whereas I'd like to use the native backup storage mechanism if possible).

I'd just like to essentially run `heroku pgbackups:capture --expire` from cron, but the Heroku commands aren't available on the server side.

Any tips would be very much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h myhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump`

Comment: Thanks Will, that's great. Do you know if it's possible to hook into the native backup storage mechanism that `pgbackups` uses? Seems like I'll need to handle the storage of the dump myself in the above command.

Comment: Our native storage is s3, and I cannot give you write permission to that. That'd be very bad. You'd have to store them on s3 yourself, sorry.

Comment: Understood! :) I don't suppose there's a way to run toolbelt commands on the server itself, then (e.g. `heroku run heroku <bla>`)? If not, S3 upload it shall be. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, take a look at https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb which is the library that the toolblet uses under the hood. The only sorta nasty thing you'll need to do is put your API token in as a config var