# Can someone from Heroku confirm my backup script doesn't violate their terms?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, backup

Following on from [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953272/what-commands-does-heroku-pgbackupscapture-run-on-the-server-to-perform-bac), I've had a look at the Heroku [client](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/pgbackups.rb) [gem](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/client/pgbackups.rb) and written a [Python script](http://github.com/BigglesZX/heroku-pgpy/blob/master/pg.py) that performs Postgres backups on Heroku in the same way as the **pgbackups** addon.

Since the removal of the **auto-month** option on the free database tier I wanted a way to perform backups automatically via Heroku Scheduler.

**However before I use this script I want to make absolutely sure it doesn't violate any Heroku terms, as that is the last thing I want to do.**

The exact functionality of this script is as follows:

In the "show" mode, it sends a GET request to the `PGBACKUPS_URL` as defined in the environment, querying the `/client/latest_backup` endpoint for the details of the latest backup taken.

In the "capture" mode, it sends a POST request to the `PGBACKUPS_URL`, endpoint `/client/transfers`, supplying the `DATABASE_URL` from which the backup should be taken.

This is exactly how the native Heroku client performs pgbackups. The script is written in Python because I needed a Python resource for my Cedar stack projects, and would be run on the server via `heroku run`.

Please could someone "in the know" tell me if this is considered OK or not?

Many thanks.

Comment: +1 Thanks for mentioning the history and prior question. As for the ToS issue, isn't that better taken up directly with Heroku support? An update here with the result wouldn't hurt if you do land up needing to contact their support.

Comment: Yeah, fair point, though I've gotten used to Stack Overflow being the first port of call for anything Heroku that ins't a case of "my app is broken."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that's fine, just keep it to like once a day. We run [wal-e](http://github.com/heroku/wal-e) for continus protection on everything. Also please know while you can figure out the API for pgbackpus easily enough, it is not public and subject to change at anytime. I've broken it on people who scripted in the past, not on purpose or vindictively, but to fix pressing problems. So just be aware that what you're doing is not really supported, but we're not going to get mad.

You might also want to look into just using straight pg_dump.

Comment: Hi Will, am I right in thinking the pgbackups:auto-month option is now free again (removing my need for this script, ha)? :)

Comment: It is free but only for production (crane+) plans. You may or may not be able to add it on dev and basic plans, but it may or may not stop working without notice.